# Connection denied to remote MySQL host through PHP but not through MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

The title really says it all. I am able to get into the remote server and run queries against the DB, but when I try to connect through PHP, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'blahblahblah' (using password: YES)

Here is the code I used to connect to the database:

```
<?php
function connectToDB() {
    $DBhost = 'remote.host.address.goes.here.com:3306';
    $DBname = 'dbName';
    $DBuser = 'myUserName';
    $DBpass = 'myPassword';
    $link = null;

    try
    {
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname", $DBuser, $DBpass);
        $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $link;
}
?>
```

Like I said, I use the EXACT same credentials in MySQL Workbench and connect just fine, and I can query all I want. I am using XAMPP, could that be causing my problems?

Comment: do u have mysql workbench installed same at mysql server machine?

Comment: no, I have MySQL Workbench at the same remote access point, same computer where I execute the PHP

Comment: do u have pdo and pdo_mysql installed? phpinfo() will output if you have these packages.

Comment: how do I check if I have those installed? I just installed XAMPP so it should be the latest version of PHP

Comment: API Extensions mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql
so looks like I am missing plain pdo?

Comment: I am not sure but i have these lines. PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers  mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL enabled
Client API version  5.1.73
But I am on ubuntu/linux

Comment: PDO is definitely installed

Answer (score 0):

Check pdo is loaded using the `extension_loaded` function.

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo') ) {
   echo "pdo extensions loaded";
}
```

Check for database-specific `PDO driver` using:-

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ) { // e.g., pdo_mysql
    echo "pdo_mysql driver loaded";
}
```

Add `port` to your connection string. Also added an attribute `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`. Try.

```
$DBhost = "remote.host.address.goes.here.com:3306";
$DBPort = "3306";
$DBname = 'dbName';
$DBuser = 'myUserName';
$DBpass = 'myPassword';
$link   = null;


$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname;port=$DBPort", $DBuser, $DBpass);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$link->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Not sure this will solve your problem.